# django-distill not exporting URL's correctly

Tags: django

I am using django-distill to create a static HTML output of my Django site.  I am having an issue with how distill converts {% static %} and {% url %} tags into relative HTML URLs.

Worth noting that I have also tried Django-bakery and am encountering exactly the same problem.

Let's start with the homepage.  This is an 'index.html' file in the parent directory.

This is the output I get from distill:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">`

The '/' at the front of the URL appears to be causing a problem.  With the code above, the style sheet does not load in the browser.  But if I manually remove the '/', the following code works:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styles.css">`

For HTML pages nested in subdirectories, the same problem is occurring but the solution is more complex.  Distill outputs the code as below:

`

However, I believe the correct output should start with "../../" to indicate to the browser that the static folder is up 2 levels in the parent directory.  The following code works correctly when I edit it manually:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/css/styles.css">`

The same problem occurs with both static links and URL links.

As I'm struggling to pinpoint where in my django code the error might be, I'm not sure which code is most relevant to share in this post.  But I will share below the relevant lines in settings.py and also my URLs which I have adapted for distill.

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "./static/"
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "productionstatic"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.StaticFilesStorage"
DISTILL_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "public")
```

app/urls.py - This is taken pretty much directly from the documentation on distill

````
from django_distill import distill_path
from .models import Destination
from .views.destinations import DestinationIndex
from .views.home import HomeIndex


def get_index():
    # The index URI path, '', contains no parameters, named or otherwise.
    # You can simply just return nothing here.
    return None```

def get_destination_slug():
    for destination in Destination.objects.all():
        yield {
            "country_slug": destination.state.country.slug,
            "state_slug": destination.state.slug,
            "destination_slug": destination.slug,
        }

urlpatterns = [
    distill_path(
        "",
        HomeIndex.as_view(),
        name="home",
        distill_func=get_index,
        distill_file="index.html",
    ),

    distill_path(
        "<slug:country_slug>/<slug:state_slug>/<slug:destination_slug>/",
        DestinationIndex.as_view(),
        name="destination_index",
        distill_func=get_destination_slug,
    ),
]
````

Many thanks in advance for your help here.

Best wishes,
Matt

Comment: Are you testing those generated HTML files by opening them with a web browser from the file system (i.e. `file:///Users/myuser/foo/index.html`)? That won't work. I believe django-distill assumes that you will be using a web server to actually serve them. In that case `/static` will be a valid path.

Comment: That's correct.  I just opened up the html files that were exported into a folder on my desktop.  On further reading, it looks like this won't work because the URL's are root-relative paths, and therefore need to be saved in the root directory which is not possible on a local hard drive.  Sounds like the files will work fine when uploaded to a web server, so I will do this right away!  Many thanks for the help.